# Understanding lexical scoping in R

Tags: r, scope

I am reading [this paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-31057-7_6) ([ungated copy](http://r.cs.purdue.edu/pub/ecoop12.pdf)) on evaluating the design of the R programming language, and am not able to understand a particular example on lexical scoping (or the absence thereof).

On page 4, the authors provide the following example of the use of the `with` function:

```
with(formaldehyde, carb*optden)
```

They go on to say:

> The astute reader will have noticed that the above example clashes
>   with our claim that R is lexically scoped. As is often the case, R is
>   lexically scoped up to the point it is not. R is above all a dynamic
>   language with full reflective access to the running program’s data and
>   representation. In the above example, the implementation of with
>   sidesteps lexical scoping by reflectively manipulating the
>   environment. This is done by a combination of lazy evaluation, dynamic
>   name lookup, and the ability turn code into text and back:

```
with.default <- function(env, expr, ...)
  eval(substitute(expr),env, enclose=parent.frame())
```

> The function uses `substitute` to retrieve the unevaluated parse tree of
>   its second argument, then evaluates it with `eval` in the environment
>   constituted by composing the first argument with the lexically
>   enclosing environment. The ‘`...`’ is used to discard any additional
>   arguments.

**How is the use of the `with` function in this case a violation of the principles of lexical scoping?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Normally when discussed in the context of R lexical scoping means that *free variables* in a function (i.e. variables that are used in a function but not defined in the function) are looked up in the parent environment of the function, as opposed to the environment of the caller (also referred to as the parent frame) but there are no free variables in `with.default` so the example does *not* illustrate a violation of lexical scoping in that sense.

For example, this illustrates lexical scoping:

```
x <- 1
f <- function() x
g <- function() { x <- 0; f() }
g() # 1
```

The answer is 1 because 1 is defined in the environment that `f` is *defined* in.   Had R used dynamic scoping rather than lexical scoping the answer would have been 0 (using the environment of the caller).  We can illlustrate how R can emulate dynamic scoping like this:

```
f <- function() eval.parent(quote(x))
g() # 0
```

ADDED:

In a comment below @hadley suggested that the authors may have been referring to the fact that the second actual argument to `with.default` is not evaluated lexically and this interpretation seems likely.   Instead of being evaluated relative to the surrounding lexical environment the second actual argument of `with.default` is read into the `with.default` function as an expression using `substitute` and then evaluated relative to the first argument using `eval`.  There is some question of what the definition of lexical scoping ought to be as it is rarely defined even when extensively discussed but typical discussions *in relation to R* refer to it as the treatment of free variables. See for example [Gentleman & Ihaka](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/downloads/lexical.pdf).

Comment: Gabor, why is the second argument in `with` not a free variable?

Comment: @fg nu, `expr` is an argument to the function so by virtue of being an argument it is defined within the function.

Comment: I think it does illustrate a violation of lexical scoping because the evaluation of function arguments is also usually lexical. Lexical scoping is not just about free variables.

Comment: @hadely, OK. I have toned it down.