# mysterious behaviour of environment in programming language R

Tags: r

I found some weird behavior of r environment, which I couldn't explain. I visited [Hadley's site](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) which talked a lot about r environment, but still couldn't get any clue. In the following, I will illustrate the problem with a simple example

```
f1 <- function(a) {
  #print(paste('print a from f1', a)) # if uncommented, will produce my expected result
  return(environment())
}

f2 <- function() {
  a <- 1
  e <- f1(a) # get the local environment of f1
  a <- 2
  return(e)
}

print(f2()$a)
```

I expect the result of `f2()$a` to be 1 (as when `f1` is called, `a` is bound to 1, which will be recorded in the local environment), but actually I got 2. **Even more weird** is that if I uncomment the `print` command in `f1`, `f2()$a` gives me 1!

I have a suspicion that what's recorded in function `f1`'s local environment for input `a` is something like a pointer (which points to the corresponding object in the calling environment). When the object in the calling environment changes, this change will also be brought to the local environment. However, this doesn't quite explain why I get expected result after uncommenting the `print` command. Could anyone help to solve this puzzle?

Comment: See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lazy-evaluation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding lexical scoping in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766649/understanding-lexical-scoping-in-r)

Comment: Thanks John @jdharrison for your prompt reply. Indeed, lazy evaluation was the cause. For the benefit of other readers, I'll put a short explanation below. According to http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lazy-evaluation, an unevaluated argument is called a promise. The first time a promise is accessed the expression is evaluated in the environment where it was created. In my example, argument `a` of function `f1` is not evaluated (if we comment out the print command) until we retrieve its value via `f2()$a`. By that time, the value of `a` in the execution environment of `f2`, is already 2.