# Make eval() use function environment rather than global environment

Tags: r, expression, environment

**EDIT**: I failed to share an MWE more pertinent to my use case.

I'm having trouble getting `eval()` to use the right environment.

```
> f = function(x) {eval.parent(parse(text = x))}
> h = Vectorize(f, "x")
> g = function() {a = 2; h("a")}
> a = 1
> h("a")
a
1
> g()
a
1
```

Above, I want `g()` to return `2`.

By the way: I read Hadley's chapters on [environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) and [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html).

Comment: This is due to lexical scoping rules in R. Use `eval.parent()` instead of `eval()`. See this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766649/understanding-lexical-scoping-in-r

Comment: `a` defined outside the function is `1` so to change it from the `g()` function, you need: `g = function() {a <<- 2; f("a")}`. As mentioned by @Psidom, this is a scope issue.

Comment: @Abdou I don't want to modify the global environment. Variable `a` should stay equal to `1` after calling `g()`.

Comment: @Psidom I tried replacing `eval` with `eval.parent` like in the page you linked, but `g()` still returned 1.

Comment: I am getting `2` with `f = function(x) {eval.parent(parse(text=x))}; g = function() {a = 2; f('a')}; a = 1`. Is this what you've tried?

Comment: @Psidom I must have messed up, the code in the comment worked. Somehow, though, it doesn't work for my larger use case, where this exists inside calls to other functions. See the edit...

Comment: What are you REALLY trying to do?

Comment: @landau `Vectorize` buries the call to `f` much deeper - you need `eval.parent(parse(text = x), n = 3)`

Comment: or maybe use `eval(parse(text = x), env = sys.frames()[[1]])` if your target environment is always going to be right after the global one

Comment: One more fancier option - if you want to iterate through all the frames to find the first one that has the variable: `f = function(x) {for (env in rev(sys.frames())) {if (x %in% ls(env)) return(eval(parse(text = x), env))}; eval(parse(text = x))}`. It's dangerous though, since the intermediate frames might have your variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Original question) This will extract the body-expression from `f` and evaluate it local to `g`:

```
 f = function(x) {eval(parse(text = x))}
 g = function() {a = 2; eval( body(f), envir = list(x="a"))}

> g()
[1] 2
```

Also can try this:

```
>  g = function() {a = 2; eval(call("f", a))}
> g()
[1] 2
```

To the downvoter: It is considered polite to explain why an answer is "not useful". We are otherwise left guessing what aspect (correctness, desirability or ???) might have triggered the vote.

After the edit: This will now deliver the requested result and probably in a less potentially offensive manner to those who adhere to strict coding "morals":

```
 g = function() {a = 2; environment(h)$FUN(a)}
 g()
#[1] 2
```

One can pull out the names and classes of the items in the Vectorized-function:

```
> ls.str(environment(h))
arg.names :  chr "x"
collisions :  logi FALSE
FUN : function (x)  
FUNV : function (x)  
SIMPLIFY :  logi TRUE
USE.NAMES :  logi TRUE
vectorize.args :  chr "x"
```

Comment: This answer is not useful because it doesn't answer the question. OP is clearly trying to make a change to `f` that will result in `g` returning what they want. Modifying `g` instead is irrelevant.

Comment: I thought the OP was implying that `f` was to be inviolate?

Comment: That's not how I read the question title, or the fact that OP tried changing `eval` to `eval.parent` to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Maybe our comment-exchange will prompt a clarification from the OP and answer HongDoi's question. I will remove my upvote.

Comment: This should work, though I am taking a different tack now.